# register_shutdown_function not catch Fatal error: (Uncaught Error unset static property example, Call to undefined function prom())

Tags: php, error-handling

i have this:

1. i have An HTTACCESS file with directive to prepend a file for config and handle error: (**it is mandatory:** According to the documentation, this file must be attached before any other php script is executed in order to obtain errors: such as E_PARSE.)

   ```
   php_value auto_prepend_file "./server/conferror.php"
   ```
2. the content of conferror.php:

   ```
   <?php
   declare(strict_types=1);
   ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '0');
   ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
   ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
   ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
   ini_set('allow_url_include', '1');
   ini_set('error_reporting', '1');
   ini_set('display_errors', '0');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");
   register_shutdown_function("ShutdownHandler");
   function ErrorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) {
       $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $error_file . '<br>' .
           "<b>Line :</b> " . $error_line . '<br>' .
           "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $error_message . '<br>';
       echo $ErrorHandler;
       exit;
   }
   function ShutdownHandler() {
       $CheckError = error_get_last();
       if ($CheckError != null) {
           $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $CheckError['file'] . '<br>' .
               "<b>Line :</b> " . $CheckError['line'] . '<br>' .
               "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $CheckError['message'] . '<br>';
           echo $ErrorHandler;
           exit;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. in my index.php i have this to start work the aplication:

   ```
   <?php
       require_once 'class.Main.php';
       $WebAPP = new CORE();
       $WebAPP->Main();
   ?>
   ```
4. in Main file i have a test, this code to unset a Static Object and Test Erros Handlers:

   ```
   <?php
   class CORE {
       public static $ObjClass;
       public function __construct() {
           self::$ObjClass['data']='data';
       }
       public function __destruct() {
           unset(CORE::$ObjClass);
       }
       public function Main() {
           #not Test on this.
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

I have 3 questions:

1. Why Event handler does not capture the following error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to unset static property CORE::$ObjClass in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class.Main.php:8 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CORE->__destruct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class.Main.php on line 8

**Second test:**

This code:

```
<?php
class CORE {
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        prom();
    }
    public function Main() {
        #not Test on this.
    }
}
?>
```

Generate this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function prom() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class.Main.php:6 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CORE->__destruct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class.Main.php on line 6

**Update:**

after much test i see that the error handler work fine with errors in declared function; but this not work in `__construct` or`__destruct` function.

Comment: @Barmar is what I try to say and explain is simply a test of implementation of the error handler.

Comment: @xakepp35 Yes of course it's easy to say everything you say ... but you do not know what's behind: Responsibilities, Costs, Expenses. Imagine telling a client that he will suffer an increase in his web license because he invested X...I do not seek to be recommended to change technology; I seek to solve this problem with the tools offered by the current platform, not a new one.

Comment: @WalterNuñez Are you sure the "./server/conferror.php" path is correct? This would mean that there is a directory, named `server`, right behind `.htaccess`, and that `conferror.php` file is contained in that directory. Can you confirm that the `server` folder is right behind the `.htaccess`?

Comment: hello yes the path are correct, and yes `.htaccess` file is near the same path that `server` directory. and on it is placed the conferror.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After doing a lot of searching in the documentation and online.**

it is not clear why the error handlers do not work correctly in the `__construct` or `__desctruct`; but as a remote idea I am assuming that these two functions are verified even before interpreting the `HTTACCESS` files or that even though the file is executed the directives: `php_value auto_prepend_file` is being executed after the two functions `__construct` and `__desctruct` are verified, this severely disrupts how handle errors and can lead to implement solutions not as comfortable as the following.

As a first point I had to implement another set that I had not read before or found, in the research I found it:

```
set_exception_handler ("ExeptionHandler");
```

and I imagine that I will have to implement others to the extent.

as a second point for this personal development: you should go from using any Method of these `__construc` and `__destruct`, and migrate to nesting everything in the declared methods.

Then the script and the structure are as follows:

**HTTACCESS Files (Same):**

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "./server/conferror.php"
```

**conferror.php(Update with new set):**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '0');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_include', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', '1');
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
register_shutdown_function("ShutdownHandler");
set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");
set_exception_handler("ExeptionHandler");
function ShutdownHandler() {
    $CheckError = error_get_last();
    if ($CheckError != null) {
        $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $CheckError['file'] . '<br>' .
            "<b>Line:</b> " . $CheckError['line'] . '<br>' .
            "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $CheckError['message'] . '<br>';
        echo $ErrorHandler;
    }
}
function ErrorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) {
    $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $error_file . '<br>' .
        "<b>Line:</b> " . $error_line . '<br>' .
        "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $error_message . '<br>';
    echo $ErrorHandler;
}
function ExeptionHandler($e) {
    $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $e->getFile() . '<br>' .
        "<b>Line:</b> " .  $e->getLine() . '<br>' .
        "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" .  $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    echo $ErrorHandler;
}
?>
```

**index.php (same not changed):**

```
<?php
    require_once 'class.Main.php';
    $WebAPP = new CORE();
    $WebAPP->Main();
?>
```

**Script Main to Test (Update: remove `__construct` and `__destruct` from programing structure):**

```
<?php
class CORE {
    public static $ObjClass;
    public function Main() {
        #not Test on this.
        self::$ObjClass['data'] = 'data';
        unset(CORE::$ObjClass);
    }
}?>
```

**For the moment is all that can make with this. i will update it if i find new information in the future.**

Answer (score 1):

1. *Why i cant unset static property CORE::$ObjClass or self::$ObjClass?*

Good question. I don't see anything in the official documentation of `unset()` or static properties that mentions this. But obviously you can't.

2. *What is the right way to do it with static property?*

You could just set it to `NULL` or an empty array.

3. *Why Event handler does not capture the following error?*

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) says:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, `E_COMPILE_WARNING`, and most of `E_STRICT` raised in the file where `set_error_handler()` is called.

This error is presumably one of these types. I'm not sure how to tell specifically what its type is.

The shutdown function is being called, but for some reason `error_get_last()` is returning `NULL` rather than the information about this error.

Comment: for question number 3, your answer is partialy Correct; but for handler fatal error i use e`register_shutdown_function() `.

Comment: I don't know. The function is being called (I added an `echo` to confirm), but `error_get_last()` is returning `NULL` so it doesn't print the rest.

Comment: i have set ini_set('display_errors', '0'); and put a echo to confirm and get and error 500 from browser...

Comment: i have detect that this work in all function declared in the class.... the problem is error that occur in __construct or __destruct