# php short print tag is avoiding buffer use and capture

Tags: php, buffer

I have this php script to capture content of  included files:

```
ob_start();
include FILEROOT . $Path;
$File = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of buffer
ob_end_clean();
```

but inside the example file `/path/file.php` this example;

```
<div id="Modal-js">
                    <?php
            #Control de opciones restaurar Contraseña del usuario
            $opt_id_req='';
            $opt_id_req_req='';
            $opt_carnet='';
            $opt_carnet_req='';
            $opt_email ='';
            $opt_email_req ='';
            $opt_username='';
            $opt_username_req='';
        ?>
        <!-- Modal para Password reset tipo Info del Servidor -->
        <div class="modal inmodal fade" id="passwordreset" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
                <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                    <form name="f-gen-userreset" id="formuserreset">
                        <div class="modal-header bg-success">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-window-close text-white"></i><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Recuperación de Contraseña.</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Por Favor Ingrese el Dato Solicitado del Sistema.</p>
                            <p class="text-warning">El Sistema le enviara una nueva contraseña; Cuando entre al sistema, se le Solicitara que Cambie su Contraseña.</p>
                            <div class="form-group row notvalidres <?=@$opt_id?> ">
                                <label>ID</label>
                                <input type="text" id="i-text-id-reset" name="i-text-id-reset" class="form-control" <?=@$opt_id_req?>>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group notvalidres <?=@$opt_carnet?> ">
                                <label>Carnet</label>
                                <input type="text" id="i-text-carnet-reset" name="i-text-carnet-reset" class="form-control" <?=@$opt_carnet_req?>>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-cls-info" name="p-adjust" data-target="f-gen-userreset">Recuperar Contraseña</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm not printing anything in php code. However, apparently the php sends to print the buffer for some reason.

**this problem occur with print short tag implementation on include file.**

[image: Result]

**UPDATE**

add to this scenario the use of an Error handler, to which you try to place an `exit;` in each function.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54259189/10771503

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '0');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
ini_set('allow_url_include', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', '1');
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
register_shutdown_function("ShutdownHandler");
set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");
set_exception_handler("ExeptionHandler");
function ShutdownHandler() {
    $CheckError = error_get_last();
    if ($CheckError != null) {
        $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $CheckError['file'] . '<br>' .
            "<b>Line:</b> " . $CheckError['line'] . '<br>' .
            "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $CheckError['message'] . '<br>';
        echo $ErrorHandler;
        exit;#if i remove this. the script and bufer work fine.
    }
}
function ErrorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) {
    $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $error_file . '<br>' .
        "<b>Line:</b> " . $error_line . '<br>' .
        "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" . $error_message . '<br>';
    echo $ErrorHandler;
    exit; #if i remove this. the script and bufer work fine.
}
function ExeptionHandler($e) {
    $ErrorHandler = "<b>File:</b> " . $e->getFile() . '<br>' .
        "<b>Line:</b> " .  $e->getLine() . '<br>' .
        "<b>Desc:</b> <br>" .  $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    echo $ErrorHandler;
    exit; #if i remove this. the script and bufer work fine.
}
?>
```

Comment: SO what gets printed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly see the image added in original post... is a text printed in spanish.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have added the script handler error, i use and Link, when i remove the `exit;` Line the buffer work correctly.